Lie theory for quantum groups?
$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$I know about quantum groups from two perspectives:

Compact quantum groups in the sense of Woronowicz.
Deformation of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra in the sense of Drinfeld & Jimbo.

There might be other perspective and constructions relevant for my question below, but I am not aware of them.
I'm interested in knowing if there is a "Lie Theory" for quantum groups. For example, consider the compact quantum group $\SU_q(2)$ in the sense of Woronowicz. $\SU(2)$ is a simply-connected Lie group that can be understood via the Lie group-Lie algebra correspondence. Questions:

Is there any notion of a "quantum Lie group" structure on $\SU_q(2)$ that allows us to associate a "quantum Lie algebra" to $\SU_q(2)$?
Is there a notion of a "quantum exponential map" that allows us to go back?
Is there a "quantum Lie group-quantum Lie algebra" correspondence that allows us to go back and forth between these pictures?

Motivation: My motivation for this question stems from my interest in spin chains with quantum group symmetry. I'm thinking about this problem in terms of the $C^*$-algebra perspective. The physics literature primarily focuses on the Drinfeld-Jimbo perspective. I'd like to know if there is a "quantum exponential map" that allows transitions between from the Drinfeld-Jimbo perspective to the Woronowicz/$C^*$-algebra perspective.

You may be interested in this post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/481181/34538

According to a theorem by von Neumann, a compact (matrix) group is a Lie group (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) if and only if it is compatible with the structure of a topological manifold. However, were you actually referring to a compact quantum group?

@SebastienPalcoux Yes, sorry. I had Von Neumann’s theorem in mind, and I wanted to refer to a compact quantum matrix group.

S. Woronowicz. Differential calculus on compact matrix pseudogroups (quantum groups). Comm. Math. Phys., 122(1):125–170, 1989.

@SebastienPalcoux I don’t know much about NCG right now. Does this framework allow us to associate a “Lie group type object” to a compact matrix group that is a Hopf algebra. Also, is there an exponential map taking us in the other direction.

@SebastienPalcoux Sorry for the typos. I’m referring to compact quantum groups. Let’s restrict to compact quantum matrix groups which are examples of compact quantum groups. I’m curious what differential calculus for such objects buy for you? Is it possible to develop a Lie theory of sorts? By that, I mean you associate a Hopf algebra to a compact quantum (matrix) group that sort of in analogy with the Lie algebra of a Lie group. Also, if there’s a way to go in the other direction with the help of an analog of an exponential map?

I apologize, but I'm unable to provide further assistance on this topic as it falls outside my area of expertise, and my knowledge is very limited. Hopefully, an expert will take over from here.

No worries at all!
